# На небольшом мониторе контент блока див не влезает на весь экран и вылезает

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой: выставил  html, body- height 100%. Затем блок див также с height 100%. И все бы ничего, но на небольшом мониторе контент блока див не влезает на весь экран и вылезает. Как сделать так, чтобы независимо от кол-ва контента и высоты монитора контент находился в пределах блока див?

CSS

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%; /*=10px*/
    min-width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url('../img/bg11.jpg');
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 35px rgba(0,0,0,.10),
                -5px 0px 35px rgba(0,0,0,.10);
    outline: 0px solid black;
    position: relative;        
}
```

Comment: @Тем Темыч, покажите ваш код. Разметку и стили.

Answer (score 1):

css

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```